# Using python zipfile to find the zip password

Tags: python, zip

First let me just say I'm a pretty noob programmer, but still I'm not the kind of guy that decided he wanted to make a MMO game. My question relates to zip files.I've been researching and I couldn't find how to use the zipfile module. My idea is that you will put in the path of the zip, and out comes the password.

Here's the command I found that I thought I code use

```
ZipFile.open(name, mode='r', pwd=None)
```

But the problem is I have no idea what i'm doing.

Comment: What is that you are trying to do? Your description is not making sense, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: Sure I think I sort of overcomplicated my description, but basically I want to have a zip file with a password, then I can run my program, and find the password.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one way of doing this and it is brute force.

So you would need a brute force algorithm (of your own liking or design) and/or a rainbow table that supplies your script with passwords. After that you just iterate over it in a loop until you find your password.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

This is simplified an non optimised code

```
rainbowTable = ['Password', '123abc', 'qwerty', 'qwerty123'] # etc...
x = 0
data = ''
for x in xrange(len(rainbowTable)):
    try:
        data = ZipFile.open(name, mode='r', pwd=rainbowTable[x])
    if data != ''
        break
```

As pointed out, the solution above is unpythonic (but imo easier to grasp if you come from another language). This is how it should be written.

```
for password in rainbowTable:
    try:
        data = ZipFile.open(name, mode='r', pwd=password)
    if data != ''
        break
    else:
        print password
```

Python however is not the best choice. You would probably want to use C for this specific task.

Here is a real world example of a Python example:
https://github.com/igniteflow/violent-python/blob/master/pwd-crackers/zip-crack.py

From the sample:

```
try:
    zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
    password = 'Password found: %s' % password
except:
    pass
print password
```

The total amount of code is 17 lines so i recommend reading it for better understanding.

Comment: Actually doing "for x in xrange(len(rainbowTable))" is very unpythonic :) Much better to iterate directly through the list like "for passwd in rainbowTable"

Comment: I know its unpythonic, but as a simplified example it at least shows where the vars are coming from. With that said i still believe your solution is superior in style and probably in speed as well.

Comment: I understand how I would try to find the password but I just don't know how to use the zip file module to check if the password is correct
Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out thanks for all your help.